# SQL Server static Analysis tool?

Tags: sql

I have an app and I want to analyze the DB side of it. Here is what I want to do with some very easy solution / tools
1. Analyze the sprocs, queries, tables, indexes and suggest what changes needs to be made?
2. What changes will improve performance? How to find them

I am looking for some static tool which can help me get this info.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you ever find a tool that worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

What engine?

Eg. for SQL Server: [Database Engine Tuning Advisor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173494.aspx).

It collects a workload (queries), analyzes the schema (tables, indexes), and suggests fixes.